I would like to set a state to true until every single card has been generated and rendered in the DOM
I have this function here that fetches data from pokeAPI but I want to set the IsLoading state to be true untill all the cards have been rendered. What I've done below seems to work sometimes and doesn't sometimes. I'm quite new to react so I'm not really sure what to ask and what more info is needed so please let me know.
useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  async function fetchAllPokemonData() {
    try {
      if (search) {
        const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${search}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        setData([]);
        setData([data]);
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) {
          const res = await fetch(pokemon[i].url);
          const data = await res.json();
          setData((prev) => [...prev, data]);
          if (filter) {
            setData((data) => 
             data.filter((item) => 
               item.types.some((type) => 
                 type.type.name === filter)));
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
  fetchAllPokemonData();
}, [pokemon, search, filter]);

Tried using try, catch and finally but it works sometimes and sometimes it just sets isLoading back to false immediately or when not all cards have been generated.

there are few things to look at.  Then not sure about the specific issue, its much easier if you make a sandbox or something to look at. Can make on codesandbox or playcode, dont even need to sign in on playcode.
First thing I would do, and I think it's generally best practice, is separate the fetching from the setting of state. It makes it easier to make changes, especially in React where you have to follow the rules of hooks. You can look up rules of hooks on React docs I think its explained fairly well.
In this case in particular there are times you are calling hooks conditionally which is against the rules of hooks, it won't work reliably.
...
if (filter) {
  setData((data) => 
    data.filter((item) => 
...

There are also calls to setData in a for loop, hook need to be called the same number of times each render.
So, you can make a number of changes so the code follow the rules of hooks. But generally also if you think about how you organize and split your code, it should you put a in position where you can more easily satisfy the rules of hooks or any rules from any framework.
Here, and in several situations, it would be beneficial to separate the fetching of pokemons, from the setting of state. So you can think of it like this: you want a function that is designed to fetch some data according to some input, and ideally the function always returns data in the same reliable format. In this case it could be an array of pokemon, or an error, or undefined, or an array of either pokemon or error, or an array the represents only the successful fetches, or other things, but that's up to how you want to design it.
Unfortunately, in React you cannot use async effect function args so you will still have to set the state in the async function you made, which is great already. But you can still separate the fetching logic, and you have to for hooks to work.
The important part is you know what data to expect, and here, in the context of react, any conditional logic should happen inside the state setter function . So in your example, the fetching logic might look like
async function fetchAllPokemonData() {
  async function getData() {
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pokemon.length; i++) {
      const res = await fetch(pokemon[i].url)
        .catch((e) => console.log(e))
        .then((res) => {
          //any processing you want to do on result
          return res;
        });
    }
  }
  const data = getData();
  setData(data);
}


So the getData function just returns an array of successfully fetched pokemon. And the you set the state once, and the set state function will always run, regardless of the outcome of the fetch.
If you wanted to streamline the code a bit, you could use something like Promise.all and create an array of fetch promises. It's a detail but nice:
async function fetchAllPokemonData() {
  const data = await Promise.all(pokemon.map(p=>fetch(p.url)))
  setData(data);
}

And then, when setting data, you can also set isLoading state
setData(data);
setIsLoading(false);

